# Is it necessary to restart node.js's http-server when updating html files

Tags: node.js

I can't find anywhere an answer for this: do I need to restart the simple [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) if I edit client files like *.html*, *.css* or *.js* (e.g.: *index.html*) from the directory the server is based on?

I want to use `http-server` for development phase, when I edit various files multiple times.

Note: this question is not related to [How can I edit on my server files without restarting nodejs when i want to see the changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925940/how-can-i-edit-on-my-server-files-without-restarting-nodejs-when-i-want-to-see-t)

Comment: generally static files served does not require a restart of server. however, if you change any backend rendering code, that will require a restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The simple `http-server` should recognize any changes you make to static files like `html`, `css`, and `js`. The simplest thing to do is give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The `http-server` uses [ecstatic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ecstatic) to serve static content. This library returns a [`Cache-Control` header](https://github.com/jfhbrook/node-ecstatic/blob/master/lib/ecstatic.js#L239)  where default timeout is 3600 seconds (1 hour).  You can change the timeout by specifying `cache` (in seconds) in the options you pass to `http-server` - which in turn will be [passed on to ecstatic](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server/blob/master/lib/http-server.js#L46)

Comment: Hmm...  I just started `http-server` locally, created an index.html file, loaded it in my browser, made an edit, and loaded it again. The edit showed up when I refreshed the page. I don't think the `Cache-Control` you're talking about affects files that have been modified.