# Without restart the server, how can I update a value in the application from the settings

Tags: node.js

Following is the implementation:

config.js

```
  - interval : 2 // in hrs
```

index.js

```
  - setInterval(removeHistory, settings.interval);

  - function removeHistory() {}
```

How the interval value can be dynamically update on changing in config file without restarting the server ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I edit on my server files without restarting nodejs when i want to see the changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925940/how-can-i-edit-on-my-server-files-without-restarting-nodejs-when-i-want-to-see-t)

Comment: Check this question and see the solutions https://stackoverflow.com/q/2925940/2520628