# What is the current options available for reload in Node JS?

Tags: node.js

What are the current available options to reload the files in node js web application development - with or without restarting - i.e both

Couple of links are out-dated now

```
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925940/how-can-i-edit-on-my-server-files-without-
   restarting-nodejs-when-i-want-to-see-t
2. https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor
3. https://github.com/kriszyp/nodules
```

Please advise

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Nodemon

```
npm install -g nodemon
# or
npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

`nodemon your-app.js`

Nodemon will watch for file changes and restart the server as needed.

2.pm2

```
npm install -g pm2
pm2 start your-app.js --watch
```

The --watch flag tells PM2 to watch for file changes.